# Contruction exercise

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

I am struggling with this exercise.

Given is the Midpoint M of a square ABCD and two straight lines g and h. 
One should construct the square ABCD having A on g and C on h [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb5AT.jpg)

My attempts: sketch[image]

I know I am looking for A and C to have the same distance to M.

Someone knows how to do this?
Bests

Comment: I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: So What I did is a sketch of how it will look like in the end. and I know I am looking A and C have to be at the same distance to M.  I added the picture of the sketch  in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw a line from $M$, parallel to one of those straight lines, let's say parallel to $h$ and call the point $P$ the intersection with the line $g$ .
Mark $A$ on $g$ such that $AP=PO$.

Line $AMC$ is the diagonal of your square.
[image]

Comment: Oh that is a really smart solution using the properties of dividing a line segment! Thank you !!

Comment: @sun, You welcome

Answer (score 1):

Let $g\cap h=\{K\}$ and $L$ be placed on the ray $KM$ such that $M$ is a mid-point of $KL$.

Now, let $h'||h$ and $L\in h'$.

Also, let $g'||g$ and $L\in g'$.

Let $h'\cap g=\{A\}$ and $g'\cap h=\{C\}$.

Thus, $ALCK$ is a parallelogram, which gives that $M$ is a mid-point of $AC$.

Now, easy to construct a square $ABCD$.

Comment: ooh alright yes ! it makes sense now ! thank you very much !!

Comment: @sun You are welcome!